# How to plot default plots from brms with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, brms

I have a bayesian model made using brms:

```
height_nb <- brms::brm(height_mm ~ dist + altitude + (1|trans.pair), seed = 010123,
                   data = dat, family = negbinomial(link = "log", link_shape = "log"), 
                   # fitting information
                   chains = 3, iter = 5000, warmup = 1000, cores = 4)
```

A plot can be made using `plot(conditional_effects(phyemp_height_nb))[[1]]` that shows the effect of `dist` on `height_mm`.

[image: plot]

How can I plot this in ggplot2 so I can edit aspects of the plot (background, axes text, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plot.brmsfit` already returns a plot of class `ggplot`. You can [add a theme](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggtheme.html) of your [choice](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggtheme.html) or [specification](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggtheme.html) like: `plot( ..., theme = your_theme_here)`.

To customize further, save the multiplot output of `conditional_effects(your_fit_here)` like so:

```
the_plots <- plot(conditional_effects(your_fit_here),
                  ask = FALSE
                  )
```

... and pick and style individual plots this way:

```
the_plots[['dist']] + ## if 'dist' is the conditional to show
    theme_minimal() + ## e. g. an existing theme of choice
    labs(x = 'the distance',
         y = 'the count',
         title = 'amazing!',
         caption = 'but mind the small print'
         )
```